# Need to configure JMeter 3.2 to use TLS 1.1 and 1.2

Tags: java, jmeter

[Error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szbsr.png)While accessing my application via JMeter I am getting SSLHandshake exception, further digging the issue found that I need to enable java/JMeter to ensure support for TLS 1.1 and 1.2

I am using JMeter 3.2 and version of jdk is 1.8.0_131

Apart from this, I have imported the security certificate to jdk/jre/lib/security folder.

could someone please help with what parameter need to be set in jmeter.property file?

I tried below but still issue is not resolved:

https.default.protocol=TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Abhishek

---------------------------New observations--------------------------------

I have done more dubbing and found that below algorithms are missing from jdk so i replaced the files local_policy & US_export_policy jar files with latest one [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html]
Missing algorithms are:
server selection: enforce server preferences
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

Now i need to know how can i add these algorithms to my jdk to support the TLSv1.2. I have attached snapshot of the error that i am getting.

Comment: Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please provide the complete exception.

Comment: I have added new observations to main question since it is too long to fit here